# What is an explicit example of a lifting in the valuative criterion for properness?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, valuation-theory, projective-schemes

The valuative criterion states that given a diagram
$$
\begin{matrix}
\text{Spec}(K) \to & X \\
\downarrow & \downarrow f  \\
\text{Spec}(D) \to & Y
\end{matrix}
$$
where $K$ is a field and $D$ a valuation ring, there should be a lifting of $\text{Spec}(D) \to X$. What is an explicit example of this for $f:\mathbb{P}^n_\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: Not exactly explicit - but I find it helpful to think of the case where $K$ is the function field of a curve over a field $k$, and $D$ is the local ring at a point on that curve.  Then the lifting says that a map from a dense subset of the curve to $\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{Z}^n \to \mathbb{Z}$ extends to a map where the point is in the domain.

Comment: Maybe I should try and look at $\mathbb{F}_p(X)$ and a valuation ring of a point on $\mathbb{P}^1_{\mathbb{F}_p}$...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a concrete example, inspired by Daniel's comment. We'll consider the projective scheme $\mathbb P_{\mathbb Z}^1$ (i.e. $n = 1$), and we'll take $K = \mathbb C(t)$ and $D = \mathbb C[t]_{(t)}$, with the morphism from ${\rm Spec \ } \mathbb C(t)$ to ${\rm Spec \ } \mathbb C[t]_{(t)}$ given by the natural ring morphism $\mathbb C[t]_{(t)} \hookrightarrow \mathbb C(t)$. We're given a morphism $\phi : {\rm Spec \ } \mathbb C(t) \to \mathbb P_{\mathbb Z}^1$ and we need to construct a morphism $\phi' : {\rm Spec \ } \mathbb C[t]_{(t)} \to \mathbb P_{\mathbb Z}^1$ such that your diagram commutes.

We can cover $\mathbb P_{\mathbb Z}^1 $ with two open affines, $\mathbb A_{\mathbb Z}^1 = {\rm Spec \ } \mathbb Z[u]$ and $ \mathbb A_{\mathbb Z}^1 = {\rm Spec \ } \mathbb Z [v]$, with $u = v^{-1}$ on their overlap. Since ${\rm Spec \ } \mathbb C (t)$ consists of a single point (namely, the generic point), the preimage of each of the two $\mathbb A_{\mathbb Z}^1$'s under $\phi : {\rm Spec \ } \mathbb C(t) \to \mathbb P_\mathbb Z^1$ is the whole of ${\rm Spec \ } \mathbb C(t)$. Let's assume that $\phi({\rm Spec \ }\mathbb C(t))$ intersects both copies of $\mathbb A_{\mathbb Z}^1$ (otherwise $\phi$ will map ${\rm Spec \ } \mathbb C(t)$ into a $\mathbb P_{\mathbb Z}^0 \subset \mathbb P_{\mathbb Z}^1$ and the story will be boring). Then the morphism $\phi$ is specified by a pair of $\mathbb Z$-algebra morphisms $f_1 : \mathbb Z[u] \to \mathbb C(t)$ and $f_2 : \mathbb Z[v] \to \mathbb C(t)$, obeying the relation $f_1(u) = (f_2(v))^{-1}$ for compatibility on the overlap.

Now let's write $f_1(u) = t^n h$, where $h$ is a unit in $\mathbb C[t]_{(t)}$ and $n$ is an integer. So $n$ is the valuation of $f_1(u)$. Then $f_2(v) = t^{-n}h^{-1}$. Clearly, at least one of $n$ or $-n$ is non-negative. So at least one of $f_1(u)$ and $f_2(v)$ is contained in $\mathbb C[t]_{(t)} \subset \mathbb C (t)$.

Without loss of generality, suppose that $f_1(u) \in \mathbb C[t]_{(t)} \subset \mathbb C(t) $. Since $f_1$ is a $\mathbb Z$-algebra morphism, it maps the whole of $\mathbb Z[u]$ into $\mathbb C[t]_{(t)}$. Using this  morphism from $\mathbb Z[u]$ to $\mathbb C[t]_{(t)}$, we get a corresponding morphism of schemes (over ${\rm Spec \ } \mathbb Z$) from ${\rm Spec \ }\mathbb C[t]_{(t)}$ to the first copy of $\mathbb A_{\mathbb Z}^1$. Composing this with the natural open immersion $\mathbb A_{\mathbb Z}^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb P_{\mathbb Z}^1$, we obtain a  morphism $\phi ' $ from ${\rm Spec \ }\mathbb C[t]_{(t)}$ to $\mathbb P_{\mathbb Z}^1$.

It remains to check that the composition of the morphism  ${\rm Spec \ }\mathbb C(t) \to {\rm Spec \ }\mathbb C[t]_{(t)}$ with our newly-constructed morphism $\phi ' : {\rm Spec \ }\mathbb C[t]_{(t)} \to \mathbb P_{\mathbb Z}^1$ is equal to the original morphism $\phi : {\rm Spec \ }\mathbb C(t) \to \mathbb P_{\mathbb Z}^1$. To check this, note that the images of both morphisms are contained inside the first $\mathbb A_{\mathbb Z}^1$, so we just need to check that the composition of the corresponding ring morphism $\mathbb Z[u] \to \mathbb C[t]_{(t)}$ with the inclusion morphism $\mathbb C[t]_{(t)} \hookrightarrow \mathbb C(t)$ is equal to the morphism $f_1 : \mathbb Z[u] \to \mathbb C(t)$. This is true by construction.

The nice thing about this example is that you can generalise it to any valuation domain $D$, and to $\mathbb P_{\mathbb Z}^n$ with $n$ greater than one. The argument will remain the same. Also notice how similar this is to the classical proof that any rational map from a smooth curve to a projective variety can be extended to a morphism: indeed, if you can think of $K$ as the function field of the smooth curve and $D$ as the local ring at a chosen point on the curve, then what we've done is essentially reproduce this classical argument.

Comment: I have not seen this classical proof that a rational map from a smooth curve to a projective variety. Do you have a reference?

Comment: It's explained rather cryptically in Hartshorne I.6. But the idea is very simple. Suppose the smooth curve is $\mathbb A_{\mathbb C}^1$ (like in my answer) and suppose we have a rational map $\mathbb A_{\mathbb C}^1 \to \mathbb P_{\mathbb C}^1$ given by $t \mapsto [1:1/t^5]$. At the moment, this rational map looks like it is not regular at $t = 0$. But it is! We just need to rewrite the map as $t \mapsto [t^5:1]$. Said more algebraically, at least one of $1/t^5$ or $t^5$ must be in the local ring $\mathbb C[t]_{(t)}$ (and in this case, it is $t^5$).

Comment: ... Of course, this argument generalises. Suppose $t$ is a local parameter on your smooth curve $C$ at a point $p$. Suppose that you're given a rational map from $C$ to $\mathbb P^2$ this time, given by $t \mapsto [1 : a/t : b/t^2]$, where $a$ and $b$ are rational functions on $C$ that are regular and non-vanishing at $p$. The rational map $C \to \mathbb P^2$ may not immediately look like it is regular at the point $p$, but once you rewrite it as $t \mapsto [t^2/b : at/b : 1]$, it is now manifestly regular at $p$.

Comment: By the way, look what goes wrong if the curve is not smooth. For example, take $C = V(st) \subset \mathbb A_{(s,t)}^2$ and $p = (0,0)$, and consider the rational map $C \to \mathbb P^2$ sending $(s,t) \mapsto [1 : 1/s  : 1/t]$. The argument doesn't work any more. There is no way of "clearing denominators". Algebraically, the problem is that the local ring at $(0,0)$ is not a valuation domain, so there is no way to "order" the singularities.

Comment: This is a very nice counter example, I really appreciate your help!